# Registering an assembly is also registering enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, dryioc

I am using DRYIOC for DI in my application. I have interfaces in my MVC application which I want to register to dryIOC. So I am using RegisterMany as below.

```
container.RegisterMany(new[] { Assembly.Load(DIAssemblyCollection["WebAssembly"]) }, 
    serviceTypeCondition: type => type.IsInterface, 
    setup: Setup.With(allowDisposableTransient: true));
```

But I am getting the error as below

> Unspecified how to select single constructor for implementation type Web.Enums.Enum1 with 0 public constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, but need to look at code first.

Meanwhile you can just filter implementation types, keep classes only:

```
container.RegisterMany(
    Assembly.Load(DIAssemblyCollection["WebAssembly"])
        .GetLoadedTypes()
        .Where(type => type.IsClass), 
    serviceTypeCondition: type => type.IsInterface, 
    setup: Setup.With(allowDisposableTransient: true));
```

[Live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZUeLbi)

#### Update

Fixed in [DryIoc 2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll)